# How to fix latest text bomb on iPhone 8?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, performance

I sent the text bomb (Italian flag with a non-english characters on either side) to my girlfriend while she was on iOS 13.3. phone hung as expected. Was able to get control after a reboot and deleted the entire chat on messages that contained said text and things seemed fine but the phone still hangs occasionally. Upgraded to iOS 13.4.1 and the issue is still there. I've tried hard reboots but that didn't help.

Is there anything else I can try except for a full reset?

I can post the actual text here but I don't want to affect anybody using an Apple OS.

Comment: Can you restore from a backup predating that text ?

Comment: Is this happening in Apple's Message app?  Or only 3rd party apps?  Or both?  Also see https://9to5mac.com/2020/04/23/italian-flag-iphone-crash-bug/

Comment: @ankii turns out she does not do any backups... As a person who religiously does backups, the notion is obsurd

Comment: @Tom Gewecke it was in the native message app.

Comment: I tried doing a hard reset, when that didn't solve it, I tried updating the software but that along with a couple of hard resets still leaves the phone seemingly randomly unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were no preceding backups, but taking a full backup, hard reset and restoring it seems to have worked well enough.